# How to print uint32_t variables value via wprintf function?

Tags: c++, c, printf, wchar-t, uint32-t

It is a well-known fact that to print values of variables that type is one of fixed width integer types (like `uint32_t`) you need to include `cinttypes` (in C++) or `inttypes.h` (in C) header file and to use format specifiers macros like `PRIu32`. But how to do the same thing when `wprintf` function is used? Such macro should expand as a string literal with `L` prefix in that case.

Comment: In which of C and C++ are you programming? Please choose at most one.

Comment: @FUZxxl Why should I choose only one?

Comment: What's the actual problem ? Does your code not compile ? Does `wprintf` display something else than you expect ?

Comment: Because usually the answer is different, but perhaps not in this case. Also, using`printf()` is not so common in [tag:c++] programs, use `<iostream>` and it deals with all this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, of course. `wprintf` accepts only wide character string as a format string.

Comment: @iharob I think in this case there is no difference. And yes, it is not so common to use `printf` in C++, but it may be useful in several cases.

Comment: @Constructor I know, that's why I like [tag:c] more.

Comment: Can you post an example that fails to compile? I just don't see the need for a wide character version of `PRIu32`.

Comment: @Constructor A question asking for code in more than one programming language is too broad. Either narrow it down to only one language or watch your question getting closed.

Comment: @FUZxxl There are [more than 30.000 such questions at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20c). Only for C++/C pair of languages.

Comment: @Constructor I don't have enough time to enforce the rules on all questions and some times (but not here), the tag combination is correct. I recommend you however, to stick to them. Questions should be about one language, except if they are about the interaction between multiple languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this will work or not actually depends on which standard of C the compiler is using.

From [this string literal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)

> Only two narrow or two wide string literals may be concatenated.
>       (**until C99**)

and

> If one literal is unprefixed, the resulting string literal has the width/encoding specified by the prefixed literal. If the two string literals have different encoding prefixes, concatenation is implementation-defined.    (**since C99**)

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So if you're using an old compiler or one that doesn't support the C99 standard (or later) it's not possible. Besides [fixed-width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) was standardized in C99 so the macros don't really exist for such old compilers, making the issue moot.

For more modern compilers which support C99 and later, it's a non-issue since the string-literal concatenation will work and the compiler will turn the non-prefixed string into a wide-character string, so doing e.g.

```
wprintf(L"Value = %" PRIu32 "\n", uint32_t_value);
```

will work fine.

---

If you have a pre-C99 compiler, but still have the macros and fixed-width integer types, you can use function-like macros to prepend the `L` prefix to the string literals. Something like

```
#define LL(s) L ## s
#define L(s) LL(s)

...

wprintf(L"Value = %" L(PRIu32) L"\n", uint32_t_value);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I am using an old compiler and it is a problem with it.

Comment: Is there any workaround for C89-compliant compilers?

Comment: @Constructor Should be possible using some function-like macros. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Constructor : `#undef PRIu32` and then `#define PRIu32 L"u"`. Then `wprintf(L"Value = %" PRIu32 "\n", uint32_t_value);` should work with old compilers, at leat it does with my old Visual Studio 6.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Do you know the purpose of macros like `PRIu32`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know its purpose, of course, but I think Michael Walz doesn't.

Comment: @Constructor of course I know its purpose, but I didn't bother to answer because JoachimPileborg was faster.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where the problem is, but here (VS 2015) both

```
wprintf(L"AA %" PRIu32 L" BB", 123);
```

and

```
printf("AA %" PRIu32 " BB", 123);
```

compile correctly and give following output:

```
AA 123 BB
```

Comment: The code that is compiled by one compiler is not necessary standard-compliant.

Comment: @Constructor I never claimed that.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your compiler does not support concatenation of differently-prefixed literals, you can always widen a narrow one:

```
#define WIDE(X) WIDE2(X)
#define WIDE2(X) L##X

wprintf(L"%" WIDE(PRIu32), foo);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/6pl2aU)

Answer (score 1):

A (weaker) alternative to using the macros from `<inttypes.h>` is to convert/cast the the fixed width type to an equivalent or larger standard type.

```
wprintf(L"%lu\n", 0ul + some_uint32_t_value);
// or 
wprintf(L"%lu\n", (unsigned long) some_uint32_t_value);
```